# Fix Runtime Error with Reverse Array Code using pointers

Tags: c++

Here's the code, I'm getting a run-time error and I'm very confused.

```
int* reversearray(int *a, int sz){
    int* array = new int[sz];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < sz; ++i){
        array[i] = a[i];
    }
    delete [] a;
    a = NULL;
    return array;
}

int main() {
    int size = 5;
    int hello[size] = {1 , 2, 3, 4 ,5};
    int* p = hello;
    int* q = reversearray(p, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Is it "How do I fix this runtime error?"? (In that case you should describe the error)

Comment: P.S. I can already see the problem with the code, but I want you to think about the question first.

Comment: You're calling `delete` on an array that you didn't allocate with `new`.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a runtime error and I don't know where

Comment: `int hello[size]` is needlessly a [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: And the elephant in the room: [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: Think on the naming. Why would a function called `reversearray`, create a new array, copy the source array into the new array, and delete the source? That seems like a bit of over-reach for a function that one would expect simply reverses an array in place. [When you break the Law of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) you get bugs. For example, what if a caller, quite reasonably, expected the array they provided to be cloned but remain usable after the reversal? It is their array after all.